# What does ってのない mean?

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language

I was talking to a Japanese person and I asked her if she liked fanfiction. She said:

> んー天の弱とか?
> これ！ってのない (笑).

I suppose she meant

Like Ten no Jaku?
This! I don't think this is it LoL.

But I don't understand the ってのない part. Is it an abbreviated form of というのではない?

Comment: Sorry if wrong, maybe there really exists an 天の弱 or **Ten** no Jaku . But maybe, even if ended with 弱, it sould be **Ama** no Jaku. Or maybe not...

Comment: へえ・・「[天ノ弱]{あまのじゃく}」っていう題名の歌があるんですね・・

Comment: Since it is hidden in the comments of the deleted answer I'll add it here. @Chocolate says: 「これ！ってのない」 is a contracted way of saying 「これというものはない」 and simply means "There's nothing in particular."

Comment: I didn't think the deleted answer was wrong at all.

Answer (score 6):

This `これ！っての` is a variant of これというもの, and [これという](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86) is a set phrase that means "noteworthy", "in particular".

> これ！ってのない (笑)
> = これというものがない (笑)
>
> Nothing in particular lol

Very literally, "A thing with which I say 'THIS ONE!' is nonexistent".

天の弱 (formally 天ノ弱 and read あまのじゃく) is the name of a song: https://youtu.be/2-zPY0vrpjQ

Similar examples:

- これという問題はなかった。
  これといった問題はなかった。
  There was no particular problem.
- これというものがあったら教えてください。(formal)
  これってのあったら教えて。(casual)
  Tell me if there is anything that interests you.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a Japanese person and it is just a contraction of というものはない which is related to this post:

[というものはない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/whats-the-meaning-of-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE)