# What does ってのには mean?

Tags: manga, japanese-to-english

[image]

What does it mean in this context??

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the original sentence.

> 二度とあのピッコロ大魔王ってのには手をださねえことだな。

Now let's simplify it a bit to mean just: *Let's not mess **with** Piccolo Daimao again.*

> 二度とあのピッコロ大魔王**に**手をださねえことだな。

Now let's add back っての. っての is a variant of 〜というもの, i.e. "*the one called...*" or simply "*that...*" So we are adding the nuance of: *Don't mess with **the one called** Piccolo Daimao again*. Or just simply: *Let's not mess with **that** Piccolo Daimao again.*

> 二度とあのピッコロ大魔王**っての**に手をださねえことだな。

Now let's add the nuance of "***Well, don't know about other demons, but this one in particular** we shouldn't mess with*." Meaning roughly: ***That Piccolo Daimao?** Yeah... let's not mess with them again*. Or: ***Don't know about the other ones**, but let's not mess with that Piccolo Daimao again*.

> 二度とあのピッコロ大魔王ってのに**は**手をださねえことだな。

For a discussion of っての, see the top answer at: [What does ってのない mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93197/what-does-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-mean)

For a really good illustration of the difference between に and には, see the top answer at: [What is the difference between "に" and "には"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)